# Does searching by id depends on number of columns in postgres?

Tags: django, postgresql

I have the following query: `MyModel.objects.filter(id__in=ids)`.

I noticed that increasing number of columns in table decreases speed of the above query.

Why is that?

Comment: My guess is that you don't have an index on `id_in` so you are getting a sequential scan with significant I/O.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus id__in is converted to SQL like -> id in ( ...), I would say that he is using Autofield in Django so he already has an index on id but still considering he is pulling all the objects, a full table scan should pop as faster in the planning phase anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query time in Postgres mostly consists of planing time, execution time and data fetch.

Planing time and execution time should not be affected by a number of columns in the table, but the data fetch phase definitely is as you are returning more data.

Also, an additional step that happens is the mapping of return data into Django QuerySet which takes more time if more columns are involved.

To limit the scope of data returned if applicable,  you can always use [values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#values), [defer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#defer), or [only](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#only).

> In some complex data-modeling situations, your models might contain a lot of fields, some of which could contain a lot of data (for example, text fields), or require expensive processing to convert them to Python objects. If you are using the results of a queryset in some situation where you don’t know if you need those particular fields when you initially fetch the data, you can tell Django not to retrieve them from the database.